# arduino user input to control on and off (with time)

Tags: arduino, serial-port, delay

I want to use bluetooth connection to control, how long something is on. So I read the Serial Input. If it is a number, I take the number and put it into a delay. After it is through, I write something and check again. If the Serial Read is not a number, it should turn off. in The problem is, the led keeps running. Do you see, what is my mistake?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define ledPin 13
#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

SoftwareSerial btSerial(rxPin, txPin);
int btData;


void setup() {
  btSerial.begin(9600);
  btSerial.println("bluetooth available");
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  serv.attach(3);
  serv2.attach(5);
}

void loop() {
  if (btSerial.available()){
    btData = btSerial.read();
      if(isDigit(btData)){
        digitalWrite(ledPin,1);
        btSerial.println("LED on Pin is on");
        delay(btData*10);
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin,0);
        btSerial.println("LED on Pin is off");
      }
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: I figured out, that the code works, if i delete the Serial Available part. Can someone explain me, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define ledPin 13
#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

SoftwareSerial btSerial(rxPin, txPin);
int btData;


void setup() {
  btSerial.begin(9600);
  btSerial.println("bluetooth available");
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  serv.attach(3);
  serv2.attach(5);
}

void loop() {
  if (btSerial.available())
    btData = btSerial.read();

  if(isDigit(btData)){
      digitalWrite(ledPin,1);
      btSerial.println("LED on Pin is on");
      delay(btData*10);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin,0);
      btSerial.println("LED on Pin is off");
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

And the reason is because the enabling and disabling was done only when there is serial data and if you put the if anywhere else it would be checked always.